# return a function result into dropdown options

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I want to return the result of a function in my component into a dropdown options:

this is my template:

```
<th>
  <p-dropdown
   [options]="getNames()"
   [required]="true"
   optionLabel="label"
   (onChange)="filterName($event.target.value)"
 >
</p-dropdown>
```

this is my function

```
    public getNames() {
    let namesLabels: any[];
    this.backendService.getNames().subscribe(response => {
    this.namesSelect = response.filter(item => item.name !== '');
    this.namesSelect .forEach(prod => namesLabels.push(prod.name));
    });
    return namesLabels;
}
```

the array namesLabels is well charged, means when I add a console.info for each element of namesLabels I found my wanted result

in the screen I don't found any value in the dropdown, any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something as below:

```
// .ts
options: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.getNames();
}

private getNames() {      
  this.backendService.getNames().subscribe(response => {
    this.namesSelect = response.filter(item => item.name !== '');
    this.namesSelect.forEach(prod => this.options.push(prod.name));
  });
  
}

//.html
<p-dropdown
   [options]="options"
   [required]="true"
   optionLabel="label"
   (onChange)="filterName($event.target.value)"
 >
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: thank you Evgency, I have an error 
TypeError: namesLabels is undefined

Comment: I have updated my answer, see getNames function definition.